# Disabling browsing ads using Flash only

Tags: browser-addons, battery-life, adblock, advertisements

I do not want to block all advertisement. However, I do want to get rid of just the ones using Flash. They drain my device’s battery so fast I cannot allow them.

Any browser extensions that take care of this? AdBlock-blocking-everything seems too dramatic.

Update: Should specify that I was looking for a blacklist solution rather than having to manually maintain a whitelist.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Ash, all of them.

Comment: Re: blacklist, this may be of interest: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9795/any-additional-security-with-large-blacklisting-hosts-file

Answer (score 2):

In Firefox:

You can use [FlashBlock](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/flashblock/?src=search) wich block, well, Flash, and allow you to make exception (exemple, allow youtube.com, but not 3rd party ad service).

Better yet would be to use [NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/noscript/?src=search) which block Flash and Javascript, redirection, cross-scripting...

I do not use other browser but Firefox, so you ll have to ask someone else to know if they (or equivalent) exist on Chromium, Chrome (eurk), Opera or other.

Comment: Yeah, +1 for NoScript. Just an all-round handy tool for things other than Flash too.

Comment: +1 for flashblock on osx chrome, battery life prolonged by 30% while browsing!

Comment: I was kind of hoping for a blacklist rather than having to maintain a whitelist.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to DrakaSAN's answer:

"AdBlock-blocking-everything seems too dramatic."

AdBlock is pretty configurable, you can choose which sites to block and white not to. Considering that ads are a not-unlikely vector for malware, running ABP and whitelisting sites you trust and/or want to support is a pretty balanced strategy.

But for safety (as suggested above), NoScript will block Flash stuff by default without any configuration. It will also take out the JavaScript on most sites though, so you need to whitelist ones you use often.

Comment: NoScript now come with generic whitelist, you just have to manually whitelist some specific site

Comment: Yes, on big well-known sites. The vast majority of sites you need to whitelist yourself (in my experience anyway).

Comment: Sure it don t whitelist everything, but the oftenness (is that even english?) of whitelisting manually is not really high for the majority of users.

Comment: I can only speak for myself, but almost every site I need to whitelist (superuser.com and sstatic.net being two apropos examples). :)

Comment: All stackexchange are blacklisted by default yes, but that only require 8 clicks the first time, and then 2 for each new stackexchange ; )

Comment: I know Draka, that was just an example. Sure it's only one click the first time, but it's for nearly every site you visit, which was my point. The NoScript FAQ shows that the default whitelist is tiny: http://noscript.net/faq#qa1_5